# Cannot change URL of opener / parent when closing pop-up in JavaScript on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a pop-up opened from a page in Chrome - I tried the following in the pop-up

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    alert('Redirecting');
    window.opener.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
};
```

However this did not work when I closed the pop-up (the alert didn't appear)

If I change this to

```
window.onload = function() {
    alert('Redirecting');
    window.opener.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
};
```

Then it works. Any idea why this isn't working? From the parent page I also tried:

```
var new_window = window.open("myPopup.html");

new_window.onbeforeunload = function() {
      window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
};
```

This similarly did not work.

Comment: You aren't allowed to stop a `window.onbeforeunload` event except with a `return` statement. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onbeforeunload).

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean by 'stopping a window.onbeforeunload event'?